# Split a column into multiple columns, also prevent leading zeros to drop in the splitted columns

Tags: r, split

I am splitting a column which has codes separated by dots (.) in one column. I am splitting that column using cSplit() but the columns then are automatically converted to numeric (if there are numbers) and the leading zeros are dropped.
For example:

```
test_data<-data.frame(mastercode=".0006488.40007.40009.0003772.0000828.0000845.0000001.")
```

this mastercode column can have codes sperated like this  and number of codes can vary.
I am splitting it like this:

```
split_data<-cSplit(test_data, "mastercode", ".")
```

the splitted column now don't have the leading zeros.
Is there any other method i can use where dropping of leading zeros can be prevented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cSplit` automatically converts columns to their respective types, you can set `type.convert = FALSE` to stop that from happening.

```
splitstackshape::cSplit(test_data, "mastercode", ".", type.convert = FALSE) 

#   mastercode_1 mastercode_2 mastercode_3 mastercode_4 mastercode_5 mastercode_6 mastercode_7 mastercode_8
#1:                   0006488        40007        40009      0003772      0000828      0000845      0000001
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `strsplit`  from `base R`

```
out <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(test_data$mastercode), "\\."))
```